# SQL Server process priority

Tags: windows, sql-server-2008, service

I made a CLR plugin for SQL Server 2008 R2 Developer edition that runs a lot of float computing on multiple threads. To test it, I used my laptop (core 2 duo 6670), and those calculations ran on 2 threads. This caused the CPU to be at 100% usage.

The question is this: When SQL process occupied 100% of CPU (for 2-3 minutes), my computer stops responding (cursor doesn't move, the clock is not updated, the entire UI is dead). It never happend with other programs, so the question is : "Does SQL Server run with a higher priority than the other services?"

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188709%28v=sql.100%29.aspx

> Use the priority boost option to specify whether Microsoft SQL Server
>   should run at a higher Microsoft Windows 2000 or Windows 2003
>   scheduling priority than other processes on the same computer. If you
>   set this option to 1, SQL Server runs at a priority base of 13 in the
>   Windows 2000 or Windows Server 2003 scheduler. **The default is 0, which
>   is a priority base of 7.**

Comment: ok. thanks. in my case, the default was not 0...or at least I don't remember changing that value.

Comment: @AndreiNeagu, the link I have mention also shows how to change or see the level. Just check for your case what is the priority level set to.

Comment: yes. the priority boost was checked. thanks again for you quick answer.